# What is the slowest growing function that cannot be proven to be total by PA?

Tags: number-theory, proof-theory

I asked the question if PA can prove any function growing faster than $f_{\epsilon_0}(n)$
 to be total. The answer was no.

What about the converse : Can prove PA every function growing slower than $f_{\epsilon_0}(n)$ to be total ? If no, what is the slowest growing function,
 which cannot be proven total by PA ?

Comment: A function f grows faster than a function g, if for every natural numer $k$, there is a natural number $n_0$, such that $f(n)>g(n+k)$ holds for all $n \ge n_0$.

Comment: We can have total recursive functions taking only the values $0$ and $1$ whose totality is not provable in $\mathsf{PA}$.

Comment: I thought so, but I was unable to come up with an example.  Is there a reasonably simple one?

Answer (score 1):

No, and there is no slowest growing function which cannot be proven total by PA.

Let $f$ be any recursive function that cannot be proven total by PA; we will require that $f$ be strictly increasing to avoid some difficulties.  Then choose a fast growing function $g$ which *can* be proven total by PA (faster than $g(n) = n$, of course).  Let $h(n) = \sup \lbrace m | g(m) \le n \rbrace$.  Then $j(n) = f(h(n))$ is a slower growing function than $f$, and it cannot be proven total by PA.

Comment: Just curious: what's the number-theoretic inverse of a function?

Comment: Are you sure $f$ is actually faster growing than $j$?

Comment: @unit I goess the term is not that well known.  I mean $h(n) = \sup \lbrace m | g(m) \le n \rbrace$.

Comment: @Hurkyl I believe so, provided that $g(n)$ is faster growing than $n$.  The idea is to take an extremely fast growing function like $g(n) = F_{\omega^{\omega^\omega}} (n)$ where $F$ is the fast growing hierarchy, and then take the inverse of that.

Comment: But extremely fast doesn't actually mean fast enough. For a counterexample among modestly growing functions, consider $f(n) = \lfloor \log \log n \rfloor$ and $h(n) = \lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor$. Then to have $f(n) > j(m)$, you could need $n \sim m^{e/2}$ or larger.

Comment: Hmm, nice example.  The problem arises if $f$ stays constant for long stretches, or if $f$ decreases, which I did not disallow. If $f$ is strictly increasing, then if $n$ grows faster than $h(n)$, then $f(n)$ will grow faster than $f(h(n))$.  I will amend the answer.